# Does the UK share Advanced Passenger Information System with the USA?

Tags: esta, us-visa-waiver-program, visa-free-entry, iran

I am considering to visit Iran. After that, I would fly to the UK, either via Qatar or Turkey.

I read that I don't qualify to enter the United States under the visa waiver program after visiting Iran. I really want to avoid getting a visa for the US, so I am wondering what the chances are that the immigration authorities will end up having records about my trip to Iran.

From Wikipedia I gathered that Iran does not stamp passports anymore, so there should not be a way for any government to know about my visit based on my passport only.

The way I understand the "Advanced Passenger Information" is that the countries I leave, enter or travel through might receive the API data from the airline I am flying with. That means that the UK would likely know that I was in Iran, and that they also have data about all my other past trips starting or ending in the UK. However, I don't really understand whether the UK will by default share this data with the US or not.

Also, what happens if I ever fly to the US using Qatar airways again? Will the US only get API data about this one trip to the US or is there a chance that they will get information about other flights with this airline?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is fundamentally about how to get away with breaking the immigration rules of the country you're visiting. We don't recommend breaking any country's rules, no matter how backwards or bigoted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as Henning Makholm observes, it's fundamentally about how to circumvent the USA's current immigration law.

Comment: I'm for leaving it open.  Whilst the question is about attempting to circumvent immigration law, it's a good opportunity to show this person and anyone in the future with a similar question why it's a bad idea to attempt such a thing.

Comment: Getting a US Visa is extremely easy for VWP citizens. You barely have to show any documents and you'll get a 10 year visa pretty much automatically. Piece of cake compared to most other countries.

Comment: @JonathanReez That is normally only true if you have a reason that you do NOT qualify for VWP (which would be true in this case).  Otherwise you will need to provide extensive proof as to why you are not simply using the VWP program.

Comment: @Dox sure, but I wouldn't worry about being barred from VWP. It's a tiny hassle. If OP needed a visa fo the Schengen countries which insultingly issue 2-3 week long visas on a routine basis it would be a different story.

Comment: South Korea is VWP country and getting a US visa for any reason is known to be a notorious process here, so 'getting US visa is easier cuz it's VWP' is not completely universal.

Comment: @JonathanReez Being barred from VWP is not a tiny hassle. US visas aren't cheap. At least in the UK, visa appointments are only available early in the morning so, unless you live close to London, you have to take two days off work and spend a night in a hotel, adding more expense. And is getting the visa really such a formality if you've been to Iran? I mean, sure, that's less hassle than the equivalent Schengen process would be, but it's much more hassle than not needing a visa at all.

Comment: Thanks for all the thoughtful replies. I have decided against traveling through Iran. As some have remarked, it is not always that simple to get a US visa, even though I qualify for one. The effort (time and money wise) to get one is high for me since I don't live anywhere near an embassy or consulate and travel extensively. I had a US visa before which has expired recently. In order to obtain it, I had to reveal information (e.g. about my financial situation), that I am not very comfortable with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple answer is that nobody can tell you.

That's not to say that nobody knows, but anyone that does know would unable to share such information publicly.

The US and the UK do have extensive data sharing agreements, many of them as a part of the "[Five Eyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Eyes)" alliance.  It is certainly very feasible (probably even likely) that such information would be shared under this agreement, especially as the basis of the travel ban you refer to is (at least in theory) related to terrorism.

You should also keep in mind that what you are suggesting would entail lying on your ESTA application, and fundamentally entering the US illegally under the Visa Waiver Program.  If you are caught, you can expect to be deported, and barred from entering the US for at least several years (not necessarily officially "banned", but your odds of having a visa application approved after both having visited Iran AND having been caught lying about that fact, would be low).

Comment: But if transiting in Qatar or Turkey, will even the UK know that the passenger originated in Iran? The UK API requirements are publicly documented and not a secret, but the documentation is in an Excel sheet, which I currently can't open.

Comment: If you bought you ticket in the UK, or if you travel includes flights that go via the UK, then the UK government will know about the entire itinerary.

Comment: The US deception ban is indefinite.  There is a waiver available, but without the waiver the banned person is permanently inadmissible.

Comment: One also needs to remember that many international networks you use without even noticing are operated by US companies: Visa, MasterCard, American Express, many of the GDS, and so on. If they really want to know, they will. Whether CBP will know it automatically is another matter, but you probably don’ want to try.